# BroadcastReceiver onReceive not changing value of boolean

Tags: java, android, boolean, broadcastreceiver

I am having a small problem with my onReceive method in my BroadcastReceiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
                paused = false;
                savePreferences("storedName", player1.getText().toString());
                savePreferences("storedName2", player2.getText().toString());
                savePreferences("lastActivity", "ma1");
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
```

This all works fine apart from the boolean value. The value is not changing. I have tried moving it outside the if statement and still no go. Any help would be great!

Comment: where you have defined the paused variable??? and you are just assigning value to it, not using pause in the code.

Comment: earlier in the activity i have assigned paused = true. I always want paused = true unless i receive this broadcast. I am later using the paused boolean to check in an if statement to see if paused == true. Although, the paused is never false after this broadcast

Comment: is your action string is correct, have you tried it assign without checking action string

Comment: the action string works correctly because the 3 strings are saved and the activity finishes. i have tried putting the paused = true statement in the onReceive before the if statement and still not working correctly

Comment: Can't say what is the issue then. Just debug and check it step by step. And if your changing ur paused value anywhere else then check it also.

Comment: since ur finishing the activity the variable pause in this class is changed and destroyed without any affect at all(think so)...Try logging the value of paused at that point...

Comment: DJphy is rite i also think and how you using paused variable value if you are finishing the activity. Thanks nice DJphy you have put a light in rite direction

Comment: the value is false after the onReceive but is true again in the onPause where the checking is. I don't know why it isn't saving the state of the boolean into the onPause method

Answer (score 0):

> earlier in the activity i have assigned paused = true.

In `onReceive` you're changing the value of `paused` then you `finish` the `activity`. So on restarting again the value true will be assigned to `paused`. The value of the variable is not retained outside the activity. I would suggest using a `SharedPreference` in place of variable `paused`.

Comment: i was trying to avoid saving the data as it would slow down the process but that seems like the only way to do it

Comment: "slow down" . No it doesn't make much difference unless you're developing for GingerBread or below.